# CSS: Issues with :before and :after

Tags: css

I'm having an issue with styling tables.  I have to create two rows of business cards on the screen.  Here is my markup:

```
<table id="contact-grid">
          <tr>
              <td class="left-box">
                  <div class="card shadow">
                      <div class="bar left"></div>
                      <img src="/images/content/winter-lab/contact-us/test.jpg" />
                      <div class="bio">
                          <h4>
                              ...
                          </h4>
                          <p>Direct: ...</p>
                          <p>Fax: ...</p>
                          <p>...</p>
                      </div>
                  </div>


              </td>
              <td class="divider">
                  &nbsp;
              </td>
              <td class="center-box">
                  &nbsp;

              </td>
              <td class="divider">
                  &nbsp;
              </td>
              <td class="right-box">
                  <div class="card shadow">
                      <div class="bar left"></div>
                      <img src="/images/content/winter-lab/contact-us/test2.jpg" />
                      <div class="bio">
                          <h4>
                              ...
                          </h4>
                          <p>...</p>
                          <p>...</p>
                          <p>...</p>
                      </div>
                  </div>

              </td>
          </tr>
</table>
```

I've deleted all of the contact info.  That's what the dots represent.

What happens is this.  I create an identical row below by copying and pasting and then change the contact information.  I then apply the following CSS:

```
.shadow {
    position: relative;
}

.shadow:before, .shadow:after {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 0;
    width: 80%;
    top: 80%;
    max-width:400px;
    background: #777;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #111;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #111;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #111;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
}

.shadow:after
{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
    transform: rotate(3deg);
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
}
```

The box shadow is only applied to the second row.  But here's what's weird.  If I transpose the two rows, then the box shadow appears on the second row, which used to be the first row.  If I create a third row, the third row gets the box shadow, too.  But not the first row.  In short, no matter what the first row is, it doesn't get a box shadow.  What's going on here?  I think the issue is the `:before` and `:after` pseudoelements, but I'm not sure because everything else is working fine.  Anyone have any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Here's a fiddle where I added a red border around each shadowed item: http://jsfiddle.net/dnS9B/1/

Comment: I am having trouble figuring out what you would like the final product to be, I see each business cards as having a shadow on it in my fiddle. A visual representation of what you are trying to accomplish would be helpful.